# Convert angle from to percentage of min/max rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that I would like to set it's pivot amount (a number between `0` and `1`). When the pivot is `0` the item will be set to its min angle, and when it is `1` the item will pivot to its max angle.

By getting this value will be based on where the users finger is on the screen, so the object will look at the finger. Converting the values between `0` and `1`.

Currently I have this, but it maxes out the pivot to one since the angle is always over 1.

```
public void SetAngle(Touch touch) {
  Vector3 position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
  float angle = Vector3.Angle(position, transform.position);
  CurrentAngle = angle;
  ToasterAnimator.SetFloat("Angle", CurrentAngle);
}
```

In the animation, the `x` rotation is `-100` when `Angle` is `0` and `-160` when the `Angle` is `1`. How can I convert the touch value from the vector3 angle to a 0-1 value?

[image: Diagram]

- Black lines = Min/Max angle
- Green lines = The desired angle
- Red line = ground
- Yellow dot = the users finger

What I need is a number between `0` and `1` of where that yellow dot is.

Comment: Is the touch.position a world position or screen position?  Unsure what this angle is even representing

Comment: no, it is screen coordinates.

Comment: is transform.position in world position?  If so... this doesn't really make much sense to compare screen coordinates with world coordinates -- and get an angle between these vectors.

Comment: "Angle" is a percentage of how far the animation offset is. Where `0` is the beginning of the animation (where x rotation is -100), and `1` is the end of the animation (where x rotation is -160).

Comment: What is your reference point? I am assuming it is to the Camera.
Currently, the 
float angle = Vector3.Angle(position, transform.position);   is getting an angle between two objects based on their world position

Comment: You 2 vectors that go from the camera to the positions

IE: v1 = position - camera.position,   v2 = transform.position - camera.position

Comment: what is the (x,y,z) in the picture where where it is green.
Is that defined as center of world?  -- In my answer below I denote that as "C"

Comment: The point where the red line and the green line meet is the position of the object I want to rotate around the `x` axis (`transform.position`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173585/discussion-between-ilan-keshet-and-get-off-my-lawn).

Comment: Have you tried making a matrix for this?

Answer (score 2):

so, going from your image:

[image]

try this code:

```
Vector3 position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, Camera.main.nearClipPlane));
// subtract transform.position to bring it to local space
Vector3 vecOA = position - transform.position;
// subtract transform.position to bring it to local space
//Vector3 vecOB = (transform.position + new Vector3(1,0,0)) - transform.position;
Vector3 vecOB = new Vector3(1,0,0);
// angle between finger and X axis
float angleAB = Vector3.Angle(vecOA, vecOB);
// angle between point 1 and X axis
float angle1B = 20;
// angle between finger and point 1
float angleA1 = angleAB - angle1B;
// angle between point 0 and point 1
float angle01 = 60;
// angle between point 0 and finger
float angleA0 = angle01 - angleA1;
// angle between point 0 and finger normalized to [0,1]
float angleA0normalized = angleA0 / angle01;
```

i hope the comments in the code are understandable

Comment: The object moves, but barely. I am not sure if it is because the math is rotating on the `z` axis, but what you have as the `x` axis is actually the `z` axis in the game.

Comment: When outputting `angleA0normalized` I am getting a number between `0.45` and `0.6` no matter where my finger is on the screen. What would be causing this?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn --1) if that is Z axis, did you change `new Vector3(1,0,0)` to `new Vector3(0,0,1)` ? --2) is it positive or negative axis `new Vector3(0,0,-1)` ? --3) are all vectors on the same plane? if you are on the YZ plane, then vecOA and vecOB must have their x value equal to zero --> `vecOA.x = 0;` and `vecOB.x = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is working the best for me:

```
public void SetAngle(Touch touch) {
  Vector3 screenSpace = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
  float angle = (Mathf.PI / 2) - Mathf.Atan2(touch.position.y - screenSpace.y, touch.position.x - screenSpace.x);
  CurrentAngle = (angle - 20 * Mathf.PI / 180) / ((60 - 20) * Mathf.PI / 180);

  ToasterAnimator.SetFloat("Angle", CurrentAngle);
}
```

I am using screen space instead of world space to calculate the percentage, which seems to be working pretty well.